# Cadence: Belt drives + Nexus 11 hubs

Tags: cadence, belt-drive, alfine

So I'm looking for a bike that has the following:
Belt Drive,
11 speed Internal hub,
Mudguards and can fit a rack at the back.

The Contenders

[Canyon Commuter 8](http://canyon.com/en/urban/commuter/2018/commuter-8-0.html)

[BMC Alpenchallenge AC01](https://www.bmc-switzerland.com/int-en/bikes/lifestyle/mountainroad-alpenchallenge-ac01-one/)

[Ghost Bikes SQUARE URBAN X7.8 AL](https://www.ghost-bikes.com/en/bikes/lanes-road/bike/square-urban-x-78-al/)

Canyon and BMC have a 50T Crank in the front and 24T sprocket at the back.
Ghost has a 46T in the front and a 24T at the back.
All 3 have Shimano Alfine 11 speed.

On my road bike I normally cycle 28-30 km/hr
and my cadence is normally between 90-100 (maybe on windy days 110).

I'm just wondering 
1. is there a system to measure gear ratio / cadence for belt drive bikes?

Not sure if this is relevant but here's someone asking about changing the front sprocket on a belt drive bike: [Gates belt drive: installing larger front sprocket](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51600/gates-belt-drive-installing-larger-front-sprocket)

Thank you in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: Cadence will be dependent on your speed and the gear you have your bike in, it has nothing to do with the belt drive compared to a chain. The important thing here is to combine the gear ratio computed for the front and rear gear with the gear ratio in the internal hub (of which I have no experience). To figure out your cadence, the best way is just to get an actual cadence sensor.

Comment: Just to clarify - this isn't a shopping question between three bikes, its more general question about drive belt bikes and ratios?  There's a good question here but it smells like product recommendation which is Off Topic.

Comment: Cadence is odd - I used to think I did about 60 RPM, but on getting a proper sensor found I was doing 80.  If you don't have a sensor, count your pedal strokes in a minute using a stopwatch or clock.

Comment: Gear ratio for belt drives is just the ratio of teeth on the belt sprockets, same as it is for chains.

Comment: @Criggie
No it's definitely not a shopping question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Gates drive belt uses an 11mm pitch between teeth.  A conventional bike chain is 1/2 inch or about 12.7mm.

The upshot is that for the same tooth count, a drive belt component will be slightly smaller than the comparable roller-chain unit with the same tooth count.

Good news - since the front chainring and rear cog use the same size, then **the ratio is all that matters**, and you can use all the normal formulae to figure out cadences.

The Shimano Alfine 11 has these ratios:

```
Ratio   0.527   0.681   0.770   0.878   0.995   1.134   1.292   1.462   1.667   1.888   2.153
Step        29.2%   13.1%   14.0%   13.3%   14.0%   13.9%   13.2%   14.0%   13.3%   14.0%
```

So assuming your sprocket is 24 tooth that equates to an 11 speed cassette with these tooth counts:

```
12.6, 16.3, 18.5, 21.1, 23.9, 27.2, 31.0, 35.0, 40.0, 45.3, 51.7
```

I couldn't find a nice calculator that deals with non-whole teeth, so I've rounded to these numbers instead.  Loss of precision detected.

```
13, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 31, 35, 40, 45, 52
```

I've also assumed a 28mm tyre with a 700c wheelsize.

Poke these numbers into http://www.bikecalc.com/speed_at_cadence  and you'll get this table:

[image: Calculated at http://www.bikecalc.com/speed_at_cadence and copyright tag left in place]

If you put the same info into http://www.bikecalc.com/cadence_at_speed then you get this table:

[image: Calculated at http://www.bikecalc.com/cadence_at_speed and copyright info in place]

**ANSWER**: on a 50:24 gear combination, with an 11 speed Shimano Alfine hub and 28-622 tyres on a 700c roadwheel, you will be doing about:

- 30 km/h in gear 9 with a cadence of 89
- 30 km/h in gear 8 with a cadence of 99

Comment: You can calculate the 46:24 tables for yourself.

Comment: Note: I have emailed Sandi from Potato Canyon Software attempting to gain approval for use of these two screenshots.

Comment: that's fantastic! Thank you so much for the explanation. 

Last week i test rode the BMC with my cadence sensor on it. 
Gear 8 and 9 on the Alfine 11 at cadence 100 and 90 respectively got me to around 30km/h. (as the table points out).

Comment: I've just received permission to use the above screenshots, from the software authors.

Answer (score 2):

A gear ratio is a gear ratio. It doesn’t matter if the gears are connected by a chain, a belt, meshing with one another or anything else. All that matters is the ratio of the number of teeth.